# cursor= collection.find_one({"name":"rain"}) pymongo query

Tags: python, pymongo

This query returns cursor object now I want to store its result in string how can it be done and tell me if it is possible in python.
I have tried

```
obj=next(cursor,None)
values=obj['values']
```

but this gives the error

```
TypeError: 'dict' object is not an iterator
```

when I tried to do

```
for i in cursor:
    string=i
    j=j+1
    for key,value in i.iteritems():
        temp=[key,value]
        string2.append(temp)
```

this returned the error

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

first of all i am confused whether this is a dict object or str object and my main aim is to copy content of this object to a string so that i can use it in my program

Comment: pymongo version that i have is 3.0.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`.find_one()`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one) method returns a single document from the database not a [Cursor](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor) that is why you get the `TypeError` in the first case. That being said you got the attribute error because `i` is the key value in your dictionary hence string and string doesn't have any attribute named `'iteritems'`. What you want is [`.find()`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find).